# How do I skip a test in the behave python BDD framework?

Tags: bdd, python-behave

I'm juggling code branches that were partly done a few months ago, with intertwined dependencies. So the easiest way to move forward is to mark failing tests on a particular branch as pending (the `rspec` way) or to be skipped, and deal with them after everything has been merged in.

In its final report, `behave` reports the number of tests that passed, the # failed, the # skipped, and the # untested (which are non-zero when I press Ctrl-C to abort a run). So `behave` as a concept of skipped tests. How do I
access that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behave doesn't skip tests, it skips steps in scenario that has already failed. Skipping tests is not supported directly, but if you need to run only portion of your tests then you can [control the execution with tags](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags).

Answer (score 32):

If you want to control things at the command line, then you do what [Tymoteusz Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36518200/) suggested in another answer. In brief, you can use whatever tag you want to mark your features and scenarios and then use `--tags` to select or deselect features and scenarios based on the tags you used. The documentation gives the example of marking slow scenarios with `@slow` and then using `behave --tags=slow` to run just the slow tests, or using `behave --tags=-slow` to exclude the slow tests. Reading the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags) is recommended to learn what syntax `--tags` allows.

By the method above, you could use `@skip` and do `behave --tags=-skip`. This will exclude everything marked with `@skip` but it is annoying to have to include the extra argument with every invocation. Couldn't `@skip` just *by itself* tell Behave to skip, without requiring any arguments on the command line?

**If you want a `@skip` tag that will skip features and scenarios marked with it, without requiring an additional argument, then, as of Behave 1.2.5, you *must* build the functionality into your `environment.py` file.** Contrarily to [what this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37288247/) suggests, it is *not* built-in. We add the functionality like this:

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
    if "skip" in feature.tags:
        feature.skip("Marked with @skip")
        return

    # Whatever other things you might want to do in this hook go here.

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    if "skip" in scenario.effective_tags:
        scenario.skip("Marked with @skip")
        return

    # Whatever other things you might want to do in this hook go here.
```

The argument to the `.skip` methods is the reason for skipping.

I always use `.effective_tags` to perform tag testing in scenarios. The `.effective_tags` field inherits tags that were set on the feature. In the case at hand here it makes no difference because if the feature had `@skip` then forcibly the scenarios in it will be skipped already. However, I prefer to stick to the general principle that tag checks in scenarios should use `.effective_tags` so that tag inheritance works.

---

Wait! Doesn't the [tutorial](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial11.html) say that `@skip` is built-in?

No, the tutorial presents things a bit misleadingly because it gives a list that shows `@skip` next to `@wip`. `@wip` is built-in so `@skip` is built-in too right? No, they are in a list is of "Predefined or often used tags". `@skip` is merely "often used". It is often used because using the word "skip" in an informative way to mark something as skipped. It does not entail that the tag is built into Behave.

Comment: A slight refinement here would be to add `and not context.config.tags.check(["skip"])` to the if statements, so that an explicit `--tags=skip` will still let you run all the currently skipped tests.

Comment: A correction to my previous above: the required addition is `and not (context.config.tags and context.config.tags.check(["skip"]))`, as an empty tag expression will otherwise report `True` for every tag.

Comment: The behave documentation has moved. The new tutorial link (pointing to tags) is https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags

Comment: @Louis: Thanks for adding this, it was really helpful, To your question to skip without command can be controlled from environment , i have added my solution below to solve that.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, new answer.

Behave currently supports filtering out tags as in the example below where all tests not tagged with @my_tag_name are executed:

```
behave --tags=~@my_tag_name path/to/my_tests.feature
```

Source: from behave help

```
# behave --tags-help
Scenarios inherit tags declared on the Feature level. The simplest
TAG_EXPRESSION is simply a tag::

    --tags @dev

You may even leave off the "@" - behave doesn't mind.

When a tag in a tag expression starts with a ~, this represents boolean NOT::

    --tags ~@dev

A tag expression can have several tags separated by a comma, which represents
logical OR::

    --tags @dev,@wip

The --tags option can be specified several times, and this represents logical
AND, for instance this represents the boolean expression
"(@foo or not @bar) and @zap"::

    --tags @foo,~@bar --tags @zap.

Beware that if you want to use several negative tags to exclude several tags
you have to use logical AND::

    --tags ~@fixme --tags ~@buggy.
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to Skip Scenarios in Python Behave and their application with example:

**All function must be declared in environment.py module:**

environment.py

## Declare skip_scenario = True in before_all()

Add a  **skip_scenarios= True** to control to skip specific scenarios from various feature files., Controller is set in **before_all** function in **environment.py****

```
def before_all(context):
    pass

    context.scenario_metadata_dict = {}
    context.feature_metadata = {'skip_scenario': True}
```

### Add a Condition in before_scenario():

if any scenario in feature file contain a tag "environmentSkip" and skip_scenario = True Then skip  only those scenarios.

```
def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    if context.feature_metadata['skip_scenario'] and "environmentSkip" in scenario.effective_tags:
        scenario.skip("Marked with skip from environment Control")
        return
    elif "skip" in scenario.effective_tags:
        scenario.skip("Marked with @skip tag in feature File")
        return
```

## Feature File:

will have the tag @environmentSkip tag if you want the tag to be skipped for a spefic scenarios.

```
  @system-testing @regression @environmentSkip
  Scenario: validate  Global Exclusion Rules for PrimaryEarlyLifeCLI Strategy
   When  derive the expected Results for global Exclusion rule NEGESTAT
      | KEY             | VALUE                                                                                              |
      |test_scenario_id |TS1_GlobalExclusion_NEGESTAT|
```

Note: Above Example handles both skip scenario, natural way of handling skip and controlled handling skip.

## Applications

Nature way : will help developers to skip scenarios for debugging purpose.

Controlled Way: will help to control scenarios for environment specific.

Same controlled can be added for before_feature() also if needed.

Answer (score -2):

You can use predefined "@skip" tag for the scenarios or features that you would like to skip and behave will automatically skip testing the scenario or the whole feature.

Comment: Untrue. I've just tried adding @skip to one of my scenarios and it was ignored by Behave 1.2.5, just as I expected. `@wip` is predefined as pointed out [here](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags). However, I do not find mention of `@skip` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry about that, skip works only for scenarios. So you can put @skip tag to skip a scenario but not the whole feature.
For mode details:
https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial11.html

Comment: The tutorial says "predefined or often used tags". `@skip` and `@slow` are not "predefined". They are "often used". In other words, you are free to use a `@skip` tag if you want, which you can then control with the `--tags` option, *just like any other tag*, which is what the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36518200/1906307) covers. You can do skip scenarios with a tag named `@skip` or `@potato` or `@asdf`. `@skip` is more readily intelligible but has no special status.